# mouse pointer to a position up in selenium

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation

[image]I have a requirement to move my mouse pointer based on a value in x-axis, such that tooltip will be shown. I am not sure how to do the same in selenium. I have seen the movetoelement, keysup. But i assume they are not the correct ones for my action.

Is there a way in selenium to do this.

Thanks in advance!!!![image: ![need to move the mouse pointer above]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsoMH.png)

Comment: I could identify an array of elements constituting each unit in x-axis. I need to move the mouse pointer in y-axis above for each array element in x-axis

Answer (score 0):

You can use Action class in selenium and move to a element position. As you are aware of your x-axis, first move your pointer to that position in x axis and then in a loop call the movetoelement of action object with (0, iterating values) till you get your preferred tool tip. This can be fine tuned if you think this grid is going to appear in the center of the screen.

Comment: Hi @user1268668, Thanks for the reply. So, in this case, do i need to loop again when i am moving to another point in x-axis or only once

Comment: @TestBud this is something you need to logic around. If in the same method you want to verify lot of other tool tips you can maintain the counter of y axis and keep verifying at every increment. Else have a generic matrix of possible y-axis and pass the value in random.